# LaTeX braces around a letter

Tags: symbols, letters, braces

[image: Braces]

Hello...I don't know the technical term for the above braces and so unable to find anything online.

I would be grateful if someone can tell me what they're called.

Thanks,

HP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Detexify

[image]

[image]

Thus, if you want to have it in math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\langle X\rangle_t$
\end{document}
```

[image]

or in text-mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\textlangle Hello\textrangle
\end{document}
```

[image]